# Pandas interpolate doesn't give monotonic results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have the following data and I want to apply the interpolate method using a spline to the last 4 numbers (I'm aware this is extrapolation):

```py
import numpy as np

x = [
    18.792571,
    19.170139,
    19.370556,
    19.393820,
    19.239932,
    18.908891,
    18.400699,
    17.892507,
    17.384314,
    16.876122,
    16.367930,
    15.859737,    
    np.nan,
    np.nan,
    np.nan,
    np.nan
]
```

I'm running pandas interpolate and a very weird thing is going on, as the code

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(x).interpolate(
    method="spline", 
    order=1
)
```

returns

```py
0     18.792571
1     19.170139
2     19.370556
3     19.393820
4     19.239932
5     18.908891
6     18.400699
7     17.892507
8     17.384314
9     16.876122
10    16.367930
11    15.859737
12    16.103099
13    15.790022
14    15.476945
15    15.163868
dtype: float64
```

So while the trend of the data is clearly negative since very early indices the interpolation produces a jump upwards. When running the same computation using scipy

```py
import scipy.interpolate as inp
train_x = [_ for _ in x if _ > 0]
s = inp.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(range(len(train_x)), train_x, k=1)
ynew = s(range(len(x)))
ynew[12:]
```

I get

```py
array([15.351544, 14.843351, 14.335158, 13.826965])
```

in this case, the interpolation doesn't have an upward change, so the results make sense to me.

My questions are, then:

- Why are the pandas and scipy results different?
- How to make pandas `interpolate` give the results that I obtain using scipy?
- Why does this upward change happen in pandas?

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Edit

Using scipy interp1d I have the same issue:

```py
s = inp.interp1d(range(len(train_x)), train_x, kind=1, fill_value='extrapolate')
ynew = s(range(len(x)))
ynew[12:]
```

Gives

```py
array([15.351544, 14.843351, 14.335158, 13.826965])
```

Comment: Hmm this is odd. The output of Pandas `interpolate` with `method=spline` actually matches data extrapolated using a linear regression on the entire dataset, interestingly. If you use a different method (eg `method=slinear`), you'll get similar results to the direct Scipy implementation. I'm actually unclear on how Pandas interprets `method=spline`, ie what exact scipy function and parameters it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, pandas uses `UnivariateSpline`, so, to obtain the same results as in pandas we can run the following using scipy:

```py
import scipy.interpolate as inp
train_x = [_ for _ in x if _ > 0]
s = inp.UnivariateSpline(x=range(len(train_x)), y=train_x, k=1)
ynew = s(range(len(x)))
ynew[12:]
```

which gives

```py
array([16.10309945, 15.79002222, 15.47694498, 15.16386774])
```

and the way to make interpolate decreasing, in this case, is passing `s = 0`:

```py
pd.Series(x).interpolate(
    method="spline", 
    order=1,
    s=0
)
```

which returns:

```py
0     18.792571
1     19.170139
2     19.370556
3     19.393820
4     19.239932
5     18.908891
6     18.400699
7     17.892507
8     17.384314
9     16.876122
10    16.367930
11    15.859737
12    15.351544
13    14.843351
14    14.335158
15    13.826965
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an answer but just some comments:

1. Pandas uses `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and not `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`. I believe these are slightly different in implementation.
2. I would use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to see if pandas and scipy match.
3. Interpolation is intended for filling *within* data. What you have is more in line with *extrapolation*. Although extrapolation can be accomplished with these methods. I would expect the results might cause peculiarities such as the upward change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I've done point 2 and they don't actually match :( Any clue on what might be going on? (it actually gives the same results as te univariatespline, as I've added in the edit)